# Re-access NFS volume from OS X Mavericks client after server reboot?

Tags: osx, nfs

My home server, running FreeBSD 10-RELEASE p7, exports NFS volumes to my MacBook Pro, running current OS X Mavericks. The MacBook mounts these via automount as `/net/servername/volume` without any config change from my side. This works fine in general.

Now, when the server has rebooted, these volumes become inaccessible. When I try to `cd` into a directory of an NFS volume, I get a `No such file or directory`, although the volume isn't even mounted, so the automounter *should* be able to just mount it. Some accesses also give me a `Device not configured`.

With former versions of OS X, a `SIGHUP` to the `automountd` helped to restore access to the NFS volumes. Now, with Mavericks, the `automountd` does not exist any more, and HUPing the `autofsd` does not help, nor does running `automount -c` to clear the cache.

What else, short of a reboot, can help?